# trying to make a javascript image carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, carousel

So I'm pretty new to coding and im trying to make a image carousel for my website (https://there.studio/). The idea is that when a user hovers over a project, an image preview appears (Already working) The image preview is 70vw and 70vh. When the user clicks to the project, I would like it to take them to the project page with the preview image to be the first image, and the user can then click through images (exactly like this website http://valentini-wiart.com)

I already had a working prototype on w3schools tryit editor, but when I paste the code into my website(I use cargo collective), it says my scripts are broken. I cant read javascript and just took the code from here(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow).

Below is my code that I made:

```
<style>
.screen {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;

}

.seventy {
width:70vw;
height:70vh;
display: flex;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.mySlides img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
overflow: hidden;

}

.prev {
  cursor: w-resize;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  width:50vw;
  height:100vh
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  cursor: e-resize;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  width:50vw;
  height:100vh
}
</style>
<div class="screen">
    <div class="seventy">

        <div class="mySlides">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2135/0257/products/ST6858-CN_2000x.progressive.jpg?v=1647839199">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">

  <img src="https://cb.scene7.com/is/image/Crate/cb_mHP_20220303_Coastal_Detail_Update?wid=769&qlt=75&op_sharpen=1">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">

  <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-1u1m3wn/images/stencil/800x722/products/3898/14934/Raphael-lowline-entertainmennt-unit-in-aus-messmate-hardwood-with-rattan-features-lifestyle-angle-crop__52553.1650590121.jpg?c=2">
</div>

<div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
<div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: *it says my scripts are broken*, there should be an error message in the console. What does it say?

Comment: I can't seem to find a console on cargo collective. Do you know if there is one and where to find it?